# Suggestion for online html code generator from richtextbox on webpage

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

do you know of an opensource project than can generate a very simple online richtextbox were a user can add **strong**, *emphasis* and other simple modifications to text so that when the user is finished (hits the submit button) the code generates an html result?

For example, [here](http://www.avidansoft.com/dsrte/index.php) this guys have a script who made almost all what i want, the only thing is when you finish the code generated its not HTML.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and with jQuery [jwysiwyg](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/simple_editor.html

Answer (score 0):

Infact the editor you mentioned itself will do the stuff.
keep formatting a text in that editor, make indentation, ordering, bold or anything.
End of the process, click on the button marked as 'html' in the toolbar- right corner.
It will give what you are looking for.

Isn't that what you r looking for?